# If a cell is blank, make no changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format phone numbers to add area codes, if the phone number doesn't have an area code. I used a large range as the number of rows is variable.

The code runs, however it is adding 64 to blank cells too.

How can I do this so the change is only applied to cells that have data, or perhaps a statement where I can basically say 'but if the cell is blank, make no change'?

```vb
Sub Change_Mobile_Format()

For Each r In Range("D2:D1000")
If Not (Left(r.Value, 2) = "64") Then
    r.Value = "64" & r.Value
End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Question, although this would be an easy question to find answer to online. I'm sure a similar has been asked.
See below, `r.value <> ""` .

`<>` means does not equal.

```
For Each r In Range("D2:D1000")
If Left(r.Value, 2) <> "64" and r.value <> "" Then
    r.Value = "64" & r.Value
End If
Next r

End Sub
```

I would encourage you to look into doing the data modification in arrays to considerably speed up code. If you decide to try, come back if you're running into problems!